# Internet Speed Calculator

Tags: python, http, networking, benchmarking

This program calculates up and downspeed of a given connection for as long as it is running.

```
#upspeed/downspeed indicator
#written by Chubak -> aurlito@riseup.net

import requests
import time
import os

def get_seconds(datetime):
    time = datetime.split(' ')[3].split(':')

    time_hours = int(time[0])
    time_minutes = int(time[1])
    time_seconds = int(time[2])

    return time_hours*360 + time_minutes*60 + time_seconds




def downspeed():
    url = "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db"

    current_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())

    file = requests.get(url)
    headers = file.headers

    file_size = int(headers['Content-Length'])/1000

    dl_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())

    time_difference = dl_seconds - current_seconds

    return round(file_size / time_difference)



def upspeed():
    current_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())

    dummy_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), 'dummy.txt')
    post_url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
    with open(dummy_file, 'wb') as dummy:
        for i in range (1500):
            dummy.write(str.encode('This is a dummy text. Its sole propose is being uploaded to a server. '))

        dummy.close()

    files = {'file' : open(dummy_file, 'rb')}

    request = requests.post(post_url, data=files)

    headers = request.headers

    file_size = int(headers['Content-Length'])/1000

    dl_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())

    time_difference = dl_seconds - current_seconds

    return round(file_size / time_difference)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        up = None
        down = None

        if up == None and down == None:
            up = upspeed()
            down = downspeed()

            print('At {0} your Downspeed is: {1}, and your Upspeed is: {2}'.format(time.asctime(), down, up))

            time.sleep(5)

            up = None
            down = None
```

I'd appreciate it if your dropped any hints about turning this into a desktop widget.

Comment: You forgot to mention that the `APPDATA` environment variable is required.

Comment: Using bigger files (especially for upload), usually around 10mb will allow the speed to settle. For example when I start uploading something, it is at 50mbps but falls to 10mbps in a few secinds.

Answer (score 5):

Your whole function `get_seconds` is not needed at all. You can use the function `time.time()`, which gives you the seconds since epoch (Jan 1, 1970 0:00:00). Subtracting two such times will yield the number of seconds passed in between. I would also do the time measurement exclusively around the actual download, otherwise you add the (small) overhead of reading the header for the file-size.

```
def downspeed():
    url = "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db"

    start = time.time()
    file = requests.get(url)
    end = time.time()

    time_difference = end - start
    file_size = int(file.headers['Content-Length'])/1000    
    return round(file_size / time_difference)
```

You should also report the units of your speeds measured. As it is, they will be KB/s, with the K denoting 1000 (as you divide by that). You should be aware that there is also a different unit, sometimes written KiB/s, where Ki stands for 1024. You should probably use the same definition, which speedtest uses, when it says the file is 100kb big.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this is the best way to measure internet speed or not. I won't comment whether this is the right approach. There are, however, some stylistic improvements that can be made.

You should run your code through [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/). Some issues could easily be addressed such as too many newlines between `get_seconds` and `downspeed`. pylint enforces two newlines.

This isn't English class, you don't have to double space your functions.

```
def downspeed():
    url = "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db"

    current_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())

    file = requests.get(url)
    headers = file.headers

    file_size = int(headers['Content-Length'])/1000

    dl_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())

    time_difference = dl_seconds - current_seconds

    return round(file_size / time_difference)
```

Just do:

```
def downspeed():
    url = "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db"
    current_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())
    file = requests.get(url)
    headers = file.headers
    file_size = int(headers['Content-Length'])/1000
    dl_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())
    time_difference = dl_seconds - current_seconds
    return round(file_size / time_difference)
```

Every once in a while you can add an additional newline for clarity, but don't over do it.

You don't need to define as many variables as you have. Consider:

```
def get_seconds(datetime):
    time = datetime.split(' ')[3].split(':')

    time_hours = int(time[0])
    time_minutes = int(time[1])
    time_seconds = int(time[2])

    return time_hours*360 + time_minutes*60 + time_seconds
```

Seeing something like `int(time[0])` might be intimidating but adding comments to explain this stuff will

```
def get_seconds(datetime):
    """
    Takes a time of day and converts it to seconds.
    Args:
        datetime: Time of day as HH:MM:SS
    """
    time = datetime.split(' ')[3].split(':')
    # Hours + Minutes + Seconds
    return int(time[0])*360 + int(time[1])*60 + int(time[2])
```

Furthermore, you don't need the `headers` variables:

```
def downspeed():
    url = "http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test100k.db"
    current_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())
    file = requests.get(url)
    file_size = int(file.headers['Content-Length'])/1000
    dl_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())
    time_difference = dl_seconds - current_seconds
    return round(file_size / time_difference)
```

And:

```
def upspeed():
    current_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())
    dummy_file = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), 'dummy.txt')
    post_url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
    with open(dummy_file, 'wb') as dummy:
        for i in range(1500):
            dummy.write(str.encode('This is a dummy text. Its sole propose is being uploaded to a server. '))
        dummy.close()
    files = {'file' : open(dummy_file, 'rb')}
    request = requests.post(post_url, data=files)
    file_size = int(request.headers['Content-Length'])/1000
    dl_seconds = get_seconds(time.asctime())
    time_difference = dl_seconds - current_seconds
    return round(file_size / time_difference)
```

By convention when you don't use a variable in a loop, you use `_`. So:

```
for _ in range(1500):
    dummy.write(str.encode('This is a dummy text. Its sole propose is being uploaded to a server. '))
```

`time_difference` is often expressed as `dt` or `ellapsed`. Consider changing it.

Maybe make the `url` variables a [default argument](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values)?